# how to change image in image switcher, how to display marker on maps, how to store variable from textview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, phpmyadmin

I am developing a simple Android apps using Eclipse Juno.
The codes are pasted at the bottom.

**First question**

What if I wish to have different image when the SelectedSubArea from previous activity is chosen? For example, if SelectedSubArea = UK, the UK image should be appear and if SelectedSubArea = US, the US image should be appear. I am using the imageSwitcher.

**Second question**

Another issue is, after the system set the text for the textview, I would like to take the value and store it into phpMyAdmin. So I have declare the variable string of name, add, desc and so on at the beginning. 
After user clicks on the AddToFavourite button, I couldn't insert the correct name, address, openingHours.... in to my phpMyAdmin. the data saved in the phpMyAdmin is not the value as already set in the textview. It will become value of "android.widget.TextView{42c32a28 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f05002d app:id/description}"

```
description.setText("Gunung Lambak has been developed as a recreational and tourist attraction called Mount Lambak Recreational Forest. Pathways and wooden bridges make it relatively easy to climb to the summit, and a picnic spot at the base of the mountain has car parking, benches, a small children's playground and toilets. There is also chalet accommodation, camping facilities and a swimming pool.");
    address.setText("Gunung Lambak Recreational Forest, 86000 Kluang, Johor, Malaysia.");
    latitude = 2.0057378;
    longitude = 103.3760577;
    openingHours.setText("n/a");
    contactNo.setText("n/a");

    name = selectedSubArea;
    desc = description.toString();
    add = address.toString();
    lat = latitude;
    lon = longitude;
    opening = openingHours.toString();
    contact = contactNo.toString();
```

**Third question**

How to show the marker of location after I have input the geolocation in my codes? I am redirect the activity to the maps that in the device.

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                             Uri.parse("geo:" + latitude +"," + longitude));
                             startActivity(i);
```

**Full Codes in java file**

```
public class AttractionDetails extends Activity implements ViewFactory 
{
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
static String URL = new ServerURL().getURL();
private static String url_add_trip = URL + "database/add_trip.php";
private static String url_add_fav = URL + "database/add_fav.php";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

String name = "";
String desc = "";
String add = "";
String opening =  "";
String contact = "";
double lat = 0;
double lon = 0;

Integer[] imageIDs = {
    R.drawable.gununglambak_1,
    R.drawable.gununglambak_2,
    R.drawable.gununglambak_3};

double latitude = 0;
double longitude = 0;

private ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;
DBAdapter dbAdapter;
final Context context = this;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.attraction_details);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String selectedSubArea = intent.getStringExtra("SelectedSubArea");

    Button btnAddToTrip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddToTrip);
    Button btnAddToFav = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddToFav);
    Button btnShowAttractionLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowAttractionLocation);
    TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
    TextView address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
    TextView openingHours = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.openingHours);
    TextView contactNo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactNo);

    if (selectedSubArea.equals("Gunung Lambak"))
    {
        this.setTitle(selectedSubArea);
        description.setText("Gunung Lambak has been developed as a recreational and tourist attraction called Mount Lambak Recreational Forest. Pathways and wooden bridges make it relatively easy to climb to the summit, and a picnic spot at the base of the mountain has car parking, benches, a small children's playground and toilets. There is also chalet accommodation, camping facilities and a swimming pool.");
        address.setText("Gunung Lambak Recreational Forest, 86000 Kluang, Johor, Malaysia.");
        latitude = 2.0057378;
        longitude = 103.3760577;
        openingHours.setText("n/a");
        contactNo.setText("n/a");

        name = selectedSubArea;
        desc = description.toString();
        add = address.toString();
        lat = latitude;
        lon = longitude;
        opening = openingHours.toString();
        contact = contactNo.toString();

        dbAdapter = new DBAdapter(context);

        imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher1);
        imageSwitcher.setFactory(this);
        imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in));
        imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_out));
        Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
        gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
            {
                imageSwitcher.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
            }
        });

        btnAddToTrip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
             public void onClick(View arg0)
             {
                 new AddNewTrip().execute();
             }
        });

        btnAddToFav.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
             public void onClick(View arg0)
             {
                 new AddToFavourite().execute();
             }
        });

        btnShowAttractionLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
         {
             public void onClick(View arg0){
                         Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                 Uri.parse("geo:" + latitude +"," + longitude));
                                 startActivity(i);
            }
         });
    }
}

class AddNewTrip extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AttractionDetails.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Adding Trip..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String trip_name = "Trip 1";
        String attraction_name = "Gunung Lambak";
        String attraction_description = "desc";
        String attraction_address = "desc";
        String attraction_opening_hours = "desc";
        String attraction_contact = "desc";
        double attraction_latitude = 2.0057378;
        double attraction_longitude = 103.3760577;

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("trip_name", trip_name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("attraction_name", attraction_name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("attraction_description", attraction_description));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("attraction_address", attraction_address));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("attraction_opening_hours", attraction_opening_hours));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("attraction_latitude", "" + attraction_latitude));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("attraction_longitude", "" + attraction_longitude));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("attraction_contact", "" + attraction_contact));
        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_add_trip,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AttractionDetails.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

class AddToFavourite extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
     @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AttractionDetails.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Adding Favourite..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            String fav_name = name;
            String fav_description = desc;
            String fav_address = add;
            String fav_opening_hours = opening;
            String fav_contact = contact;
            double fav_latitude = lat;
            double fav_longitude = lon;

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fav_name", fav_name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fav_description", fav_description));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fav_address", fav_address));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fav_opening_hours", fav_opening_hours));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fav_latitude", "" + fav_latitude));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fav_longitude", "" + fav_longitude));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fav_contact", "" + fav_contact));
            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_add_fav,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

public View makeView()
{
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    return imageView;
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private int itemBackground;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c)
    {
        context = c;
        //---setting the style---
        TypedArray a = obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
        itemBackground = a.getResourceId(
        R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
        a.recycle();
    }

    //---returns the number of images---
    public int getCount()
    {
        return imageIDs.length;
    }

    //---returns the ID of an item---
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    //---returns an ImageView view---
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 120));
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
        return imageView;
    }   
}
}
```